# using min() function in a pandas datagram with an exception value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a min() function in a pandas dataframe with the intent to get the minimum values.

However, in the DataFrame, all "bad data" values have been replaced with -9999999.

How do I ignore that value in a min() function?  that value carries no data value.

here's some code:

```
# the for I, row loop is designed to identify which rows are data rows and which rows are not.  the bottom portion filters out non-data rows.  
xl = pd.read_excel(location, header=None, sheet_name=0)
keep = []
for i, row in xl.iterrows():
    cells = 0
    numbers = 0
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        cells += 1
        if type(column).__name__ in ('float', 'int') and not pd.isnull(column):
            numbers += 1
        #print(i,column)
    #print(i, cells, numbers, numbers/cells*100)
    if numbers/cells*100 > 50:
        keep.append(i)


#filters out those records that are most likely NOT data rows
df = xl.iloc[keep]
#apply's -9999999 default value to conform to data type standards
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).fillna(-9999999)

# ToDo: Ignore -9999999 when performing the below functions
dfmax = df.max()
dfmin = df.min()
```

Thanks!

WARNING:  if I don't conform the default value, min() and max() functions do not report values of all records as the column will be a mixed datatype.

Comment: Can you add the actual code here?

Comment: By any chance is the bad data located across entire columns and rows, or is it single cell?  An example of the data would help.

Comment: ok.  first thing I do is eliminate non-data rows in the DataFrame.  Then I look for bad cells in the columns.

Comment: Something like `dfmin = df.values[df.values > -9999999]).min()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to get the values over that number:

```
df.values[df.values > -9999999].min()
```

In general, *Numpy's Not a number* `np.nan` is the best representation of a bad data instead of an actual numerical value, and in Pandas v>0.15, it writes NULL to SQL.

Comment: how does np.nan work with .to_sql? does it set null?

Comment: Wouldn't `nsmallest` just give you `-9999999` twice? And `df[df.values > -9999999].min()` does not do what you want either, if anything `df.values[df.values > -9999999].min()`...

Comment: @acree123 `np.nan` outputs NULL to sql.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works great.  There is so much to learn between numpy and panda.